# While iterating through a list, check the next x values until one fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of values, some positive some negative. What I would like to do is iterate through the list but with each value, check the next value, if the sign matches, combine them and check the next value adding that if the same, until it finds a negative/positive number of a different sign appending the summed numbers to another list. I want to do the same thing for negatives.

Here is a minimal working code to check 2 values at a time, but I am not quite sure how to check an arbitrary number of values (until the sign changes). It is also important to keep them in their order.

```
arr=[1, 2, 1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -2, -2, 3, 1]
data=[]
for i in range(1, len(arr), 2):
        if arr[i-1] > 0 and arr[i] > 0:
            val=arr[i-1]+arr[i]
            data.append(val)
        elif arr[i-1] < 0 and arr[i] < 0:
            val=arr[i-1]+arr[i]
            data.append(val)
        else:
            data.append(arr[i-1])
            data.append(arr[i])
            
    if len(arr) % 2 != 0:
        data.append(arr[(len(arr))-1] )
```

arr=[1, 2, 1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -2, -2, 3, 1]

I would like data =[4,-1, 2, -1, 2, -4, 4] eg: the first 3 numbers in arr were all positive, summed and appended to data. arr[3] and arr[4] were neg and positive so they were just appended, same with arr[5] and arr[6], arr[7] and arr[8] are both negative, combined, and appended to data, arr[9] and arr[10] were both positive, combined and added to the list. There could be any number of either positive or negative values in a sequence in the list though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
arr = [1, 2, 1, -1, 2, -1, 2, -2, -2, 3, 1]
data = []
i = 0

while i < len(arr):
    current_sum = arr[i]
    i += 1
    
    while i < len(arr) and ((current_sum > 0 and arr[i] > 0) or (current_sum < 0 and arr[i] < 0)):
        current_sum += arr[i]
        i += 1
    
    data.append(current_sum)

print(data)
```

You initialise the `current_sum` and in the inner while loop when the sign changes or the end of the list is reached, you append the `current_sum` to the list.

Comment: thank you that works perfectly! I was thinking while loops, but I couldn't quite get nested ones to work.I'll have to look more at what you did so I can understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby

data = [sum(g) for _, g in groupby(arr, lambda x: x > 0)]
```

Comment: Thank you, I will also give that a try as well and look into groupby. Some interesting things in there, haven't seen _, before and while I have seen lambda, I haven't used it. Always willing to expand my horizons though.

Comment: May I know what the issue is? As far as I can tell, this is correct and pythonic.